# How to create an SVG marker symbol layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, svg, qgis-2.14

I am using Qgis 2.14.3-Essen on a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.8.5.

I have a number of SVG files stored in a directory named QgisSymbols.

I have set the path to the Qgis directory in Settings/Options/System/SVG paths.

I have also added the svg file directories to the svg directory within the QGIS application (Contents/Resouces/svg).

On the properties/Style tab when I select the symbol layer type as 'SVG marker' I don't see any SVG groups? I just get the message 'This layer doesn't have any editable properties' - even when the layer I am trying to change the symbol for is editable?

I have tried this with a line layer and a point layer and get the same result for both. I want to use SVG symbols for lines and points but can't.